# how to retrieve all columns value in a single row in Android Parse

Tags: android, parsing

For example, said I got 20 rows in a particular parse Class, 5 columns in total. How can I retrieve all the column values of a single row.

I found the code in .Net format, but I don't know how to do this in android. Thanks

```
List<String> list = new List<String>();
                IEnumerable<ParseObject> res = await query.FindAsync();

                foreach (var i in res)
                {
                    var s = i.Get<string>("category");


                    list.Add(s);


                }


                category.ItemsSource = list;
```